# Window of another process comes between my two forms

Tags: c#, winforms, z-order

I have a .Net winforms (C#) application with its main form (form A), and it opens different other forms as non-modal (so that user can work on either the main form or child forms independently)

In some cases, the child form (form B) opens another pop up form (form C). When this pop up is closed, another window from another application (e.g.chrome, outlook, VS) comes in between my main form and child form. Usually this other window is the one which was just underneath my main window.

Before closing the form, the z-order is: Outlook, Form A, Form B, Form C

After closing form c, the z-order changes to: Form A, Outlook, Form B

I didn't want to specifically BringToFront() my Form A, because there could be many instances of Form B at a given time, and I don't want to make my Form A over the Form B's.

Any idea what could cause this kind of behavior? Is there a way to make sure all my application's forms are above other windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the child forms Owned by the form that opens them.  This will maintain a relative z-order.

```
public partial class FormA : Form
    {

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        FormB f = new FormB();
        f.Show(this);
        }
    }
```

---

```
public partial class FormB : Form
    {

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        FormC f = new FormC();
        f.Show(this.Owner);
        }
    }
```

This has the side effect that when a form's owner is closed/minimized, its owned forms also will close/minimize.

Comment: And also this has the side effect of, if I open another instance of Form B, I cannot access the previous Form B instance. I need to have access to all the forms at all times :(

Comment: @Anuruddha, there is nothing in this that prevents you from accessing previous instances.  The only caveat is that owner window (FormA in this case) can not cover a owned window.  A good summary of the owner-owned windows relationship is presented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Remarks);  its for the WPF window, but the list is applicable to WinForm windows as well.